# Identificando trechos em comum em duas strings PHP

Tags: php, string

Preciso fazer uma comparação de strings fora do padrão em PHP. Tenho 2 strings como abaixo:

```
$primeira = 'asdasdasdTESTEasdasdasdasd';

$segunda = 'lkijlikjTESTEilkjik';
```

Como faço de forma dinâmica para saber se a primeira e a segunda variável contém a mesma sequencia de caracteres iguais? Nesse caso exemplificado pela sequencia de caracteres "TESTE".

Comment: Talvez [essa questão](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16521079/1342547) do SOen ajude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Criei uma função que compara segmentos das strings e retorna as palavras iguais em um array:

```
function palavras_iguais($string1, $string2, $minlen = 5) {
    $strlen1 = strlen($string1);
    $strlen2 = strlen($string2);
    $palavras = array();
    for($i=0; $i < $strlen1; $i++) {
        $palavra = substr($string1, $i, $minlen);
        if (strpos($string2, $palavra) !== false) {
            $j = $minlen;
            do {
                $j++;
            } while (strpos($string2, substr($string1, $i, $j)) !== false && $j < $strlen2);
            $palavra = substr($string1, $i, $j-1);
            $i += strlen($palavra)-1;
            $palavras[] = $palavra;
        }
    }
    return $palavras;   
}
```

**Teste 1:**

```
$primeira = 'asdasdasdTESTEasdasdasdasd';
$segunda = 'lkijlikjTESTEilkjik';

print_r( palavras_iguais($primeira, $segunda) );

// Retorno:

Array
(
    [0] => TESTE
)
```

**Teste 2:**

```
$primeira = 'asdFINALasdasdTESTEaTESTE2sdasdasdasdTESTENOFINAL';
$segunda = 'lkiTESTE2jlikjTESTEilkjTESikTESTENOFINALjhfdgkFINAL';

print_r( palavras_iguais($primeira, $segunda) );

// Retorno:

Array
(
    [0] => FINAL
    [1] => TESTE
    [2] => TESTE2
    [3] => TESTENOFINAL
)
```

**Teste 3:**

```
$primeira = 'asdaTSCsdasdTESTEasdasdasdasd';
$segunda = 'lkijlikjTESTEilkjTSCik';

print_r( palavras_iguais($primeira, $segunda, 3) );

// Retorno:

Array
(
    [0] => TSC
    [1] => TESTE
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Pensei numa abordagem um pouco diferente das demais. Quis evitar loops aninhados, mas não testei se isso tem impacto positivo na performance. Funciona assim:

- Cria uma array de grupos de caracteres da primeira string. Por exemplo, com `$minlen=2`, a string `"abcde"` é dividida em `["ab", "bc", "cd", "de"]`.
- Verifica se cada par ocorre na segunda string. Se ocorrerem em seguida, considera uma única palavra (por exemplo, se a segunda string contiver `"abc"`, os dois primeiros pares são encontrados em sequência).

Acho que fica mais fácil entender em forma de código:

```
function matchingSubstrings($str1, $str2, $minlen=2) {
    $grupos = [];
    for($i=1; $i<strlen($str1); $i++) {
        array_push($grupos, substr($str1, $i-1, $minlen));
    }

    $palavras = [];
    $temp = '';
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

    do {
        if($k = strpos($str2, $grupos[$i], $j) !== false) {
            $j += $k;
            $temp .= $temp === '' ? $grupos[$i] : substr($grupos[$i], -1);
        } else {
            if($temp !== '') array_push($palavras, $temp); 
            $temp = '';
            $j = 0;
        }
        $i++;
    } while($i<count($grupos));

    return $palavras;
}
```

Um teste com repetições:

```
matchingSubstrings('nnnabcnnnabcnnn', 'kkkabckkkabc');
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => abc
)
```

Se a repetição não for desejada no retorno, basta trocar a última linha da função por `return array_unique($palavras);`.

Essa função também funcionou com os testes da [resposta do Jader](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34134/74) (a saída foi idêntica).

**[Demo no ideone](http://ideone.com/aGCGNz)**

Answer (score 3):

Não creio que exista uma função nativa do php que faça isso.

Encontrei uma [solução](http://www.christopherbloom.com/2011/02/24/find-the-longest-common-substring-using-php/) no google que resolve o que você precisa.

```
function longest_common_substring($words)
{
    $words = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', $words));
    $sort_by_strlen = create_function('$a, $b', 'if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { return strcmp($a, $b); } return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;');
    usort($words, $sort_by_strlen);

    // We have to assume that each string has something in common with the first
    // string (post sort), we just need to figure out what the longest common
    // string is. If any string DOES NOT have something in common with the first
    // string, return false.
    $longest_common_substring = array();
    $shortest_string = str_split(array_shift($words));
    while (sizeof($shortest_string)) {
        array_unshift($longest_common_substring, '');
        foreach ($shortest_string as $ci => $char) {
            foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
                if (!strstr($word, $longest_common_substring[0] . $char)) {
                    // No match
                    break 2;
                }
            }

            // we found the current char in each word, so add it to the first longest_common_substring element,
            // then start checking again using the next char as well
            $longest_common_substring[0].= $char;
        }

        // We've finished looping through the entire shortest_string.
        // Remove the first char and start all over. Do this until there are no more
        // chars to search on.
        array_shift($shortest_string);
    }

    // If we made it here then we've run through everything
    usort($longest_common_substring, $sort_by_strlen);
    return array_pop($longest_common_substring);
}
```

Essa solução retorna o maior conjunto de caracteres similares dentre de um array de strings.

A implementação fica bem simples:

```
$primeira = 'asdasdasdTEStEasdasdasdasd';
$segunda = 'lkijlikjTESTEilkjik';

echo longest_common_substring([$primeira, $segunda]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).Para mais detalhes [click aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

```
if (strpos($primeira, $segunda) !== false)
    echo 'true';
```

Comment: Lendo melhor a questão não creio que isso soluciona o problema.

Comment: Essa função não atende minha necessidade pois preciso checar se existe nas duas variáveis existe uma parte iguai, representada por "TESTE", independente dos caracteres vindos antes e depois do "TESTE".

Comment: Esta não é uma crítica à resposta, mas sim a quem votou sem ler a pergunta: me surpreende duas pessoas terem dado voto positivos, visto que ela não passa nem perto de responder ao que foi perguntado.